# Why is there error buildozer debug and sdl 2?

Tags: android, buildozer

I'm trying to create an .apk from .py with buildozer debug, but there's always an error when loading sdl2 image.
It worked once, and now it always shows this error. the download url is not working.

.......................................................................................

```
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[DEBUG]:   -> running mkdir -p /home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/sdl2_image
[DEBUG]:   -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:    SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:   Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[DEBUG]:   -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.4.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 947, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1414, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 918, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1276, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 725, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 558, in build_recipes
    recipe.download_if_necessary()
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 362, in download_if_necessary
    self.download()
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 412, in download
    self.download_file(self.versioned_url, filename)
  File "/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 218, in download_file
    urlretrieve(url, target, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1397, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 1 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 2 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 4 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 8 second(s)...# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/isi/Schreibtisch/Project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
```

how can i download the sdl2, or is there a problem with buildozer, sec?

Answer (score 0):

This could occur due to two reasons. Either your network connection is too poor or unstable or that SDL servers are down.

In the first case, try another network.

In the second case, there really isn't much that can be done. This happens some times. The only way to fix it is to wait for some time for SDL serves to go back online.

Comment: Thanks! servers are up now again so it is working now.